# How to create a file on the command line and pass as an argument to a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I call a library like this:

```
# myFile.txt is a file that already exists read by `grun`
$ grun TestLexer tokens -tokens myFile.txt
```

However, instead of passing a file, I'd like to create/re-create that every time I run it in the command-line such as something like the following:

```
$ grun TestLexer tokens -tokens "echo 'x+1' > myFile.txt"
```

What would be the proper way to actually do that?

Comment: Why not `echo 'x+1' > myFile.txt && grun TestLexer tokens -tokens myFile.txt`?

Comment: I find your question unclear, since I don't know _grun_. Perhaps you can define, what _grun_ exactly expects as a parameter to `-tokens`. If it is a filename, will this file be read or written by _grun_? Can the parameter also be something different as a file name? For instance, some programs accept the special name `-` to denote standard input.

Comment: @user1934428 updated with a code comment in the question the clarify.

Comment: I **guess** that that parameter is solely used for input in _grun_ (you didn't clarify **this** at all). In this case, why don't you have your script create a suitable file before calling _grun_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash has [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

You can run a command and make its output available to another command as if it were a file:

```
$ grun TestLexer tokens -tokens <(echo 'x+1')
```

To see what is happening, consider:

```
$ echo <(echo 'x+1')
```

---

`grun` reads from stdin if a filename is not provided, so you could also pass a here-doc / [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), or pipe in the data:

```
$ grun TestLexer tokens -tokens <<<'x+1'
```

```
$ echo 'x+1' | grun TestLexer tokens -tokens
```

Comment: That works too, or if `grun` will read `stdin`, a herestring will work `grun ... <<< "x + 1"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I got the impression the `-tokens` argument expects a filename

Comment: Yes, I am still a bit unclear on that, if it takes POSIX type args, then `-` could be passed as the filename to read from `stdin`. But without knowing more about `grun` it's just a bit of speculation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but I think I'm wrong. Antlr grun/testrig documentation seems sparse. It may well be able to read stdin or a heredoc.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, "the definitive ANTLR4 reference" says: Omitting input-filename makes rig read from stdin.

Comment: Mystery solved. So all bases are covered. The only last choice is a personal choice for the questioner whether he wants a persistent file left over in the end. In this case he can just add an additional redirection and he's covered.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be an option?

```bash
echo 'x+1' > myFile.txt && grun TestLexer tokens -tokens myFile.txt
```

or perhaps in the case that this can be run multiple times concurrently (in case myFile.txt would be overwritten) or you dont want to commit to a filename:

```bash
tmp=$(mktemp) && echo 'x+1' > $tmp && grun TestLexer tokens -tokens $tmp  && rm -f $tmp
```

Comment: I'd vote for that too `:)`